# ASP.Net, CORS, and HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, web-config, cors

I want to access some things in local and session storage located on the same domain, but using a different protocol. The data is cached on HTTP and needs to be retrieved under HTTPS.

How can I configure ASP.Net to allow this without hard-coding the web site name in my web.config? This is what I have now

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://my-web-site" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you also need Access-Control-All-Methods?

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE" />
```

Comment: It's all new to me. What I really want to do is avoid hard coding the web site name with https/http into the first setting.

Comment: I read a bit about this, but it's a bit more bleeding edge than I can stomach. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API

Comment: You can use the value `*` for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin setting.

Comment: It looks like that's my only option unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you follow the methods suggest here:
http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/